# ORA-00907 when using sql to call a function

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to select from a function returning a custom type which is a table

I thought this would work

```
 select * from table(FW.CustomFunction ('value1','value2'))
```

which returns an

> ora-000902: invalid datatype

ok so I thought this would work:

```
select * from table(cast  FW.CustomFunction ('value1','value2') AS CustomTypes.CustomTable  )
```

but I get

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Any clues what I am missing?
Schema Definition follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE FW.CustomTypes IS
    TYPE CustomTable IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
        INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
END CustomTypes;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FW.CustomFunction ( param1 IN VARCHAR2, param2 IN VARCHAR2 ) RETURN CustomTypes.CustomTable IS
    CustomTableToReturn CustomTypes.CustomTable;
BEGIN
    LOOP
        ...add items to CustomTableToReturn

    END LOOP; 

    RETURN CustomTableToReturn;
END;
/
```

Comment: Not sure about oracle, but in sql-sever this is the way `select * from yourTableValuedFunction () where somefield = 'value1' etc`

Answer (score 2):

Arguments to cast require parentheses around them:

```
table(cast ( FW.CustomFunction ('value1','value2') AS CustomTypes.CustomTable ) )
```

Comment: ahh..I missed adding it but I did try this.  It returns a ORA-00902: invalid datatype....Here was the format:  select * from table(cast ( FW.CustomFunction ('value1','value2') AS CustomTypes.CustomTable ))  It seems to me this was the one that should work.